# Bad practice to set parameter variable name of method to the name of the data type in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, naming

Is it poor practice to name the variable in a method a lowercase version of the class name?

In the case below: `string.class` ==> `String`

```
def title=(string)
  @title = string.split(' ').map.with_index do |word, i|
    i == 0 ? word.capitalize : title_form(word)
  end.join(' ')
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends. You want to be using names as close as possible to the problem domain.

In your case, a more appropriate name for the parameter would be `uncapitalized_title`, `raw_title`, `unformatted_title`, simply `title` or something similar.

On the other hand, if you were writing a gem that extends `String` or does something with generic strings, then `string` is likely the right name.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @DavidSawatske, yw. Naming things is one of the two hardest things in programming. The other being cache validation and off-by-one errors. xd

Answer (score 1):

It is poor practice, because it's usually not very descriptive. Additionally, since Ruby doesn't actually care that you're passing a `string` it could be misleading.